# Perfect matching in the n-unit-cube, Is hyperplane statement wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory, bit-strings

I was thinking about perfect matchings in the graph of the unit-cube of dimension $n$: $Q_n = [0,1]^n$. ($0$-$1$-strings of length n are vertices. Two of such are connected by an edge iff. they differ by only 1 bit (i.e. Hamming distance is equal to 1)).

Suppose you're given an arbitrary perfect matching $M$ in $Q_n$. Is it possible to find a facet $F$ of $Q_n$ such that all matching edges $e = (v,w) \in M$ that cover a vertex in $F$ lie in $F$? Stated differently, if $v \in F$ and $(v,w) \in M$ for some vertex $w$, does that imply that $w \in F$? This statement should be equivalent to finding a separating hyperplane, that separates $Q_n$ into two $(n-1)$-cubes, such that no matching edge crosses the hyperplane.

What do you think, is this true or false? Obviously its false for $n=1$ but I think it should hold for all $n \geq 2$, but can't prove it!

Any advice on how to prove it or a counterexample is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: By “facet” do you mean an induced $Q_{n-1}$-subgraph?

Comment: Yes. With facet I mean an $n-1$ dimensional face of $Q_n$ viewed as a polytope. Each facet has one coordinate fixed to $0$ (or $1$) and all others are still in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: [Is this](https://imgur.com/a/I6LgnNL) a counter example? I’m not sure I can find a sub-cube that only fully contains matching edges. I apologize in advance for the quality — I’m not at my desk at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but to be quite honest, I am not sure whether I understand your drawing correctly.

Comment: [Let me know if this is any better](https://imgur.com/fGljK1z).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a perfect matching in $Q_4$ that does not have this property.

[image]

Comment: I think we came up with very nearly the same matching!

Comment: It's quite possible that there is only one construction up to symmetry here. We have 4 directions, and in each one of them we want at least one (and therefore at least two) edges.

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty sure that this holds!